# Struts2 integration testing

Tags: java, solr, struts2, integration-testing, jboss-arquillian

I have a Struts2 application running on Tomcat. I can unit test my models and classes because a lot of it is just calling a function or instantiating a class which I understand.

The problem is I'm at a loss on how to do integration testing with my Struts actions. For instance I have an action which:

1. Parses a user request
2. Creates an object
3. Connects to a Solr database
4. Returns a JSON string to the user

My current understanding is that I can either use mocks or in-container testing. [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/) seems like a good framework, particularly because I want to try in-container with a dummy database, but I'm still unaware of how to actually test the points above.

Any help, book reference etc would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at S2 junit plugin: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/struts-2-junit-plugin-tutorial.html.

Comment: Well if you just want to do out-and-out system testing, then selenium is really awesome. For more resolution junit (as per last suggested comment) would be quite useful, and DBUnit looks really interesting for a practical way to work with data across across a number of system tests.